# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (for attribute reference)

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, custom-attributes

I have this line in my account_particle.xml layout

```
            android:padding="?attrs/disc_padding"
```

this attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="AccountParticle">
    <attr name="apStyle" format="enum">
      <enum name="header" value="0"/>
      <enum name="list_item" value="1"/>
    </attr>

    <attr name="text_margin_start" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="text_margin_end" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="text_margin_right" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="text_margin_left" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="disc_padding" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="disc_imageViewSize" format="reference"/>


  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and this styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.ap.header" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="disc_padding">@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Theme.ap.list_item" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="disc_padding">@dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_avatar_margin_start</item>



      </style>
```

Why do i get this compilation error?

```
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'padding' with value '?attrs/disc_padding').
```

AccountParticle

Comment: Typo. There's no `s` on `attr`. That is, it should be `android:padding="?attr/disc_padding"`.

Comment: but it's on attrs.xml

Comment: That's just a file name. The actual resource will be created in the `R.attr` class. In fact, it doesn't matter what you name any file under the `res/values*/` folders, or in which file you put any resource there; they all get processed according to their type, like `<attr>`.

Comment: can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I can put that in an answer. Since you intended for it to be `attrs`, this isn't just a simple typo. Gimme a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for referring to a theme attribute value in a layout attribute is:

```
prefix:attribute="?attr/themeAttribute"
```

That is, `attr` instead of `attrs`.

Though you may have defined that attribute in a file named `attrs.xml`, the filename is actually irrelevant. When resources are being built, every file under the `res/values*/` folder is processed, regardless of the filename.

This effectively means that you can name your files there whatever you want, and you can put any resources there in whichever file you want. They will all be processed according to their type, like `<attr>`, `<color>`, `<string>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the attribute usages it should be `?attr/` instead of `?attrs/`.

---

But you have another issue in your `attrs.xml` file. The problem is that you are declaring the following reference inside a `declare-styleable`:

```
<attr name="text_margin_start" format="reference"/>
<attr name="text_margin_end" format="reference"/>
<attr name="text_margin_right" format="reference"/>
<attr name="text_margin_left" format="reference"/>
<attr name="disc_padding" format="reference"/>
<attr name="disc_imageViewSize" format="reference"/>
```

This references should be moved outside the `declare-styleable`

#### Why

The `declare-styleable` is used to define a group of `attrs` that will be used in the context of a custom view. In your case, the `disc_padding` is used outside the context of an `AccountParticle`.

Documentation reference: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr

Comment: thanks, but i meant the layout is account_particle.xml