# FileProvider failing to parse XML

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to use a `FileProvider` but it is failing to parse the XML and throwing this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This is the calling code:

```
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed download of update file");
            statusMessage = "Completed download of update file";

            Uri uri;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                if (context != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Context is: " + context.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Context is null");
                }
                if (context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority) != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Authority is: " + context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority));
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Authority is null");
                }
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "outputFile is: " + outputFile.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "outputFile is null");
                }
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), outputFile);
                statusMessage = "uri set";
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "URI successfully set");
            statusMessage = "URI successfully set";
```

None of the parameters are `null` and "URI successfully set" is never logged.  So it seems to me that the problem lies in the XML files.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_trans"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@strings/file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

file_provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

Any ideas about what I can try to resolve this issue please?

Comment: That Exception can happen when you call `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` with an authority that doesn't match the value in the manifest. Your value there looks suspect – `@strings/file_provider_authority`. Why is `strings` plural? Normally, it's `@string`. Do you somehow have two different `file_provider_authority` values? Are you getting an error or warning on that line?

Comment: Changing from `strings` to `string` has solved the problem - many thanks.  But why is it singular when the XML file is `res/values/strings.xml` which is plural?

Comment: I explain that in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53359699). It's specifically about `attr` resources, but it's the same for `string` resources, as well. I'm kinda surprised that built successfully, actually, but I suppose you can do all sorts of odd stuff with Gradle.